# Exploring RAM contents

Tags: applications, memory

I would like to explore the contents of the RAM my application is using? I would like to see if I can find that string I allocated. Any suggestions to print out the entire contents of my application's memory to the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

To find the C string `”FooBar”` in your heap:

1. `$ lldb PathToYourAppBundle/Contents/MacOS/YourAppName`
2. `(lldb) command script import lldb.macosx.heap`
3. `(lldb) r`
4. Pause execution with <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.
5. `(lldb) cstr_refs -m FooBar`